# Exclude where clause based on function specification

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I developed the following function:

```
create function kv_fn_ValuationPerItem_AW (@dDate date, @active bit)
returns table
as

return
(
select
    Code                                                    ItemCode
,   Description_1                                           ItemDescription
,   ItemGroup
,   Qty_On_Hand                                             CurrentQtyOnHand
,   AveUCst                                                 CurrentAvgCost
,   Qty_On_Hand*AveUCst                                     CurrentValue

from        _bvSTTransactionsFull   t
inner join  StkItem                 s   on  t.AccountLink = s.StockLink
where       ServiceItem = 0
and         ItemActive = @active
and         TxDate  <=  @dDate
group by    Code,   Description_1,  ItemGroup,  Qty_On_Hand,    AveUCst
)
```

The function requires two parameters:

1. Date
2. Is the item Active - 1 = Active & 0 = Inactive

If I use the function as stipulated above, by specifying **1** for the Active Parameter, then the results will only be for Active Items.

If I specify **0**, then it'll return all inactive Items.

How do I alter this function to cater for Active Items or both Active & Inactive?

i.e. if the parameter is **1**, the where clause should read as `ItemActive = @active`, but when it's **0**, the where clause should read as `ItemActive in (1,0)`, How do I change the function to work like this?

I tried a case, but my syntax is not correct...

Comment: So you want Active and inactive rows? Pass `NULL` for `@active` and handle it in your `WHERE`? Not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: You want this: and (@active = 1 or ItemActive = @active) ?

Comment: So when the parameter is 1, it should only give active items, but when the parameter is zero, it should return active & inactive items... Hope that makes sense.

Comment: i.e. if the parameter is `1`, the where clause should read as `ItemActive = @active`, but when it's `0`, the where clause should read as `ItemActive in (1,0)`, How do I change the function to work like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100),Active BIT);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('Row 1 is active',1)
                         ,('Row 2 is active',1)
                         ,('Row 3 is inactive',0)
                         ,('Row 4 is inactive',0);

DECLARE @OnlyActive BIT=0; --set this to 1 to see active rows only

SELECT *
FROM @mockup m
WHERE (@OnlyActive=0 OR m.Active=1);
```

The idea is: If the parameter is set to 0 this expression is always true, if not, the column `Active` must be set to 1.

**Hint:** I used paranthesis, which was not needed in this simple case. But in your more complex `WHERE` clause they will be needed...

**Hint2:** I named the parameter `OnlyActive`, which expresses a bit better what you are looking for. You might turn the parameter to `ShowAll` with an invers logic too...

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo, your answer gave me an idea how to change it. If I change the where clause to `ItemActive in (0,@active)`, it caters for both. Please change your answer to cater for this, then I'll mark yours as the answer...

Comment: If you change your where clause to `in(0, @active)` you'll get all the records when `@active` equals 1. If anything, change it to `in(1, @active)` - though I would recommend the `or` over it for readability. I also liked Shnugo's Hint2 - renaming the parameter for clarification is a good advice.

Comment: You are correct @ZoharPeled, I'll change it accordingly. Thanks both of you for your advice! Please alter your answer to look like my answer and I'll award the final answer to you...

Comment: @Birel, I'm glad to help you... but to be honest: I do not know what changes you actually want... Accepting an answer means: *"This answer helped me to solve this issue"* or in other words: *"Another user with a related question will find the solution most likely in this answer"* It is up to you, which answer you accept. You can accept your own, mine or Zohar's (who was seconds faster than me ;-) ). But I think that my answer (with a *stand-alone* sample) in a more general point of view will help a future visitor more than a very specific answer, where the solution is a bit hidden... Up to you

Comment: Understood @Shnugo, thank you for your valuable input!

Comment: @Birel one more hint, as we are taking the "how to vote on SO" tour at the moment ;-) Acceptance and votes are two separate concepts. Thank you for clicking the acceptance check at my answer. As a next step it would be nice to up-vote Zohar's answer (clicking the up-triangle), and - if you want - you might do this with mine too... Happy coding ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as adding an `or` to your where cluase:

...

```
and         (ItemActive = 1 OR @active = 0)
```

...

BTW, you might want to do it like this instead:

```
and         (ItemActive = @active OR @active IS NULL)
```

which means that when you pass in `1` as `@active` you'll get only the active items, when you pass in `0` you'll get only the inactive members, but when you pass in `null` you'll get all records, regardless of the value in the `ItemActive` column.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Shnugo & Zohar for your answers,

Please amend your answers, then I'll mark yours as the answer.

The solution to my problem was to alter the Function as following:

```
create function kv_fn_ValuationPerItem_AW (@dDate date, @active bit)
returns table
as

return
(
select
    Code                                                    ItemCode
,   Description_1                                           ItemDescription
,   ItemGroup
,   Qty_On_Hand                                             CurrentQtyOnHand
,   AveUCst                                                 CurrentAvgCost
,   Qty_On_Hand*AveUCst                                     CurrentValue

from        _bvSTTransactionsFull   t
inner join  StkItem                 s   on  t.AccountLink = s.StockLink
where       ServiceItem = 0
and         ItemActive in (1,@active)
and         TxDate  <=  @dDate
group by    Code,   Description_1,  ItemGroup,  Qty_On_Hand,    AveUCst
)
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you want (I think the system lets you do that only 48 hours after the question was asked or something like that).

Comment: Thanks Zohar, I will do so, however credit still goes to you and @Shnugo! :-)

Comment: @Birel: The *credit* on stack overflow is the up-vote. Since you've crossed the 15 rep-points border you are allowed (and urged) to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say *thank you*. Acceptance is more or less meant for a future visitor to quickly find the most helpful answer. Happy coding!

Comment: @Birel As Shnogo wrote - credit in SO is the answer's score. You can (and should) upvote useful answers, and downvote non-useful answers. Unlike accepting an answer, you can vote on as many answers per Q&A as you want to.